Why is my BME280 sensor returning 0 for all data values?
My BME280 is returning 0 for temperature in Celsius, 0% humidity, 0.00 pressure (hPa) and 44330.00m for altitude. I am connecting it with I2C on a Raspberry Pi Pico and everyone on the team has checked the wiring so we are relatively certain that it is not an issue. We are using the test code from the AdaFruit BME280 Page.
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BME280.h>

#include <SPI.h>
#define BME_SCK 18
#define BME_MISO 19
#define BME_MOSI 23
#define BME_CS 5

#define SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA (1013.25)

Adafruit_BME280 bme; // I2C (default pins for Raspberry Pi Pico: GPIO 4 (SDA), GPIO 5(SCL)
/*
Adafruit_BME280 bme(BME_CS); // hardware SPI
Adafruit_BME280 bme(BME_CS, BME_MOSI, BME_MISO, BME_SCK); // software SPI
*/
unsigned long delayTime;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("BME280 with Raspberry Pi Pico");

  Wire.setSDA(4);
  Wire.setSCL(5);
  Wire.begin();
  bool status;

  // default settings
  // (you can also pass in a Wire library object like &Wire2)
  status = bme.begin(0x77);  //I have tried using 77, 76(default), 80, and blank
  if (!status) {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid BME280 sensor, check wiring!");
  }

  delayTime = 1000;

  Serial.println();
}

void loop() { 
  printValues();
  delay(delayTime);
}

void printValues() {
  Serial.print("Temperature = ");
  Serial.print(bme.readTemperature());
  Serial.println(" *C");

  // Convert temperature to Fahrenheit
  /*Serial.print("Temperature (fahrenheit) = ");
  Serial.print(1.8 * bme.readTemperature() + 32);
  Serial.println(" *F");*/
  
  Serial.print("Pressure = ");
  Serial.print(bme.readPressure() / 100.0F);
  Serial.println(" hPa");

  Serial.print("Altitude = ");
  Serial.print(bme.readAltitude(SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA));
  Serial.println(" m");

  Serial.print("Humidity = ");
  Serial.print(bme.readHumidity());
  Serial.println(" %");

  Serial.println();
}

In theory this code should work. Is there an issue with our sensor? I also don't really understand where the 44330.00 is coming from with the altitude.
This is what it's returning:
Temperature = 0.00 *C
Pressure = 0.00 hPa
Altitude = 44330.00 m
Humidity = 0.00 %

are you using the correct pins?

If bme.begin() returns false, you should abort() or lock the sketch in an infinite loop, in order to prevent it for ever executing loop(). Otherwise you may miss a “Could not find a valid BME280 sensor” message. As for the altitude, it's just what their atmosphere model outputs for a zero pressure.

By the looks of it you have connected the BME sensor via SPI
#include <SPI.h>
#define BME_SCK 18
#define BME_MISO 19
#define BME_MOSI 23
#define BME_CS 5

but you are trying to use it as an I2C device
Adafruit_BME280 bme; // I2C (default pins for Raspberry Pi Pico: GPIO 4 (SDA), GPIO 5(SCL)
/*
Adafruit_BME280 bme(BME_CS); // hardware SPI
Adafruit_BME280 bme(BME_CS, BME_MOSI, BME_MISO, BME_SCK); // software SPI
*/
unsigned long delayTime;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("BME280 with Raspberry Pi Pico");

  Wire.setSDA(4);
  Wire.setSCL(5);

If you want to connect via SPI, comment out
Adafruit_BME280 bme

And uncomment this if BME_MOSI, BME_MISO, BME_SCK are not the boards default SPI Pins:
Adafruit_BME280 bme(BME_CS, BME_MOSI, BME_MISO, BME_SCK); // software SPI

Otherwise (and preferably because hardware SPI is faster) uncomment:
Adafruit_BME280 bme(BME_CS); // hardware SPI

Note: The altitude reading is likely calculated from the zero pressure reading so you would expect it to be large.

You're currently using 0x77, but many breakout boards use 0x76 by default. Try changing the I2C address to 0x76 in your code:
status = bme.begin(0x76);


If that doesn't work, try using an I2C scanner to check what I2C addresses are detected by your Pico. Here's a simple I2C scanner code to run:
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("I2C Scanner");

  for (byte address = 1; address < 127; address++) {
    Wire.beginTransmission(address);
    if (Wire.endTransmission() == 0) {
      Serial.print("I2C device found at address 0x");
      Serial.println(address, HEX);
    }
  }
}

void loop() {}

To make the I2C scanning task easier, you can make an I2C scanner shield.
https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/OLED_0_96__I2C_Scanner_Shield.html
